# Is Keeping a Small List of Strings as a Text File (And Reading Them in) Better Than Keeping Them in Code

Tags: string

I have a small list of around 500 strings (all just common words). I've heard it's best practice to keep them as a file and read the strings into the code. But I'm wondering what is the downside for keeping them just in the code in the first place? This is not an opinion based question, I'm asking about the actual quantitative trade-offs between the 2 approaches.

Thank you!

Comment: in perfomance term, hard-coded data is fast.
but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Comment: Thank you, but could you explain how Magic numbers are related to this issue? Does it mean that the code is just harder to read?

Comment: right, is not exactly magic numbers, see that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding